# Making a passenger top in rails 4 from a belongs_to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 classes that have associations with each other

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :passengers
end
```

and a class

```
class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :trip
end
```

And my Idea is to make a top of X passengers that have been to most trips.

I have found out that you can count entries of each passenger using something like

```
def count_passenger_trips
  pas_names = Passenger.pluck(:name)

  pas_names.each do |p|
    puts p
    puts Passenger.where(:name => p).count
    pas_names.delete(p)
  end
end
```

But it does not really return the right result(always keeping the last entry in the array and not counting it in/deleting it from the array)

I guess I could make a new array with key-value pairs and then order them by counts. Wanted to know what might be the problem for not counting in the last passenger and also maybe there is a simpler way to do this(because I want to add a block of Top passengers to my webpage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `name` is the unique identifier for these `Passenger` entities, you could do something like this:

```
Passenger.group(:name).count
```

This should give you back results like:

```
{
  'Jane Doe' => 25,
  'Bob Smith' => 35,
  'Heywood Johnson' => 1,
}
```

These can be pricey queries if you don't have indexes set up for them, so beware.

If you wanted to, say, only find people with at least 10 trips, you could do this:

```
Passenger.group(:name).having('count(*) >= 10').count
```

Comment: This works. But after I group people by name I get an array with {"name" => count} how do I then sort them and list them out (say top 5)?

Comment: Just vanilla Ruby at that point.  You could sort the hash descending and get the top 5 with `.sort_by { |k,v| -v }.first(5)`.  There's likely a way to do it in your SQL server of choice, if performance becomes an issue.